# Who gives the RSA private key to the opposite party

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have a very fundamental question on RSA keys. I understood the algorithm at high level. So, when I encrypt using a public key, it can only be (quickly) decrypted using a private key. So if I am communicating with you. How do you get the private key that you will use to decrypt my message? Wasn't this the original issue with DH algorithm as to how to share the keys beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you identified, RSA uses a public and a private key. You never give out your private key, but your public key can be sent to others.

Say Alice is communicating with Bob, Alice will give Bob her public key which Bob uses to encrypt a message being sent to Alice. That encrypted message can only be decrypted using Alice's private key, so only Alice can decrypt it with her private key.
The same in the reverse. A message to Bob is encrypted with his public key, which can then only be decrypted using his private key.

The public key can only be used for encryption, and the private key can only be used for decryption.

You can read more about RSA here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/rsa-encryption/

Comment: Yes. I think as a new learner for the RSA my basic confusion was that I thought both Bob and Alice need to have the private key and that means it has to be shared first. But your explanation helps. Bob will give a public key (like an open lock) to Alice to lock/encrypt his message and send back to Bob. The message can "only" be opened by Bob.